# A pair of tables?

Tags: database, data-structures

I had this idea for working with two sets of data that are about equal in importance. In a project I'm working on, there are files with associated tags. Originally I just kept the data in a hash table with the files as keys and each file's tags as value. But there are often times when I want to look at all of the tags and say something about the files.

I decided I could keep track of two hash tables, a forward `(file0->(tag1 tag2):file1->(tag2 tag3))` and a reverse `(tag1->(file0):tag2->(file0 file1):tag3->(file1))`. I haven't tried it yet, because I'm not sure if it's as useful as I think it might be or I'm just off my head. Is there any advantage to this? Prior usage?

Comment: Because I can't answer my own question yet: My question is about a many to many mapping. In a database, this typically employs three tables, one for each set of data and a cross-reference table that relates them. My method basically embeds this third table into the other two. Whether there's any advantage to that I can't say, but I'll refer to the literature on this one.

Answer (score 1):

That will work if both keys and values are unique.  If not, you will need a "[MultiValueMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html)" that can handle multple entries per key.

Comment: I think I was unclear. It should be more obvious what I'm doing now.